# Creating a surjective transformation from $\ R^4 \rightarrow R^3 $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ T: \mathbf R^4 \rightarrow \mathbf R^3 $ and $\ T(1,3,-1,0) = (1,0,-4) , T(1,2,1,2) = (2,0,-8) $ and I need to find a transformation that will satisfy those conditions and will also be surjective.

Comment: Honestly just trying $\ T(x,y,z,t) = (x_1,x_2,x_3) $ and thinking which values of $\ x_1,x_2,x_3 $ will satisfy but couldn't come up with any.

Comment: Do you know about bases of vector spaces in combination with linear transformations?

Comment: The only tricky part here is that the two vectors given in $\mathbb{R}^4$ map onto the same linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. You'll need two vectors that are linearly independent from each other and from both $(1,3,1,0)$ and $(1,2,1,2)$ that map onto two vectors that are linearly independent of $(1,0,-4)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which preserve the linearity of the transformation. This is easier than it seems at first glance.

Comment: So If I understand you correctly I have two vectors of $\ R^4 $ that map onto the same subspace of $\ R^3$ therefore I need to find other two vectors in $\ R^4 $ that are linearly independent of those two we already have and that will each map onto different subspace of $\ R^3 $, am I correct?